# basic auth user management

Tags: linux, server, basic-authentication

I would like to have some expert knowledge regarding the Nginx server basic auth that I'm currently planning on using [this](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/), is it possible to use one basic auth username & password account to have access by 1,000 users? is there a limitation to using one basic auth account? is there server load capacity I should concern about?

I'm assuming at least a couple of 100 users will access the static page on the server simultaneously.

the server specs are a Linux server with 4GB memory and 2 core.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are no significant limitations to using basic auth user/pass to "protect" a static page, except that you should be aware that it is generally against security best practice. It is likely that your basic user/pass will be brute-forced or shared at some point in a way that might defeat the protection you are hoping to have enabled.

Note that basic auth doesn't restrict brute-forcing so script kiddies might just launch attacks against your server until they determine the user/pass you've got in place. You can combine basic auth + logging + something like fail2ban to prevent brute force attacks. There's also no per-user attribution as to who accessed the content if you're reusing one account for thousands of users. I'm guessing you're fine with that, but I'd generally not recommend this setup myself.

As for your question of whether or not the server spec is capable of a couple hundred simultaneous requests, that is entirely up to your use case. How big is the content being served? Can it be served from memory? Will you pre-compress the static content, or serve it non-compressed? If you enable on-the-fly compression, it's less likely your server will have more problems at high concurrency.

Generally nginx is a very efficient server and should be fine based on the high level info you've provided, but there's no guarantees without more detail.

Good luck!

Comment: much appreciated for the long explanation, it seems the only method I can make work combining basic auth + logging + fail2ban.